# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

In my page A, there is a textarea defined like this:

```
<textarea readonly wrap="Physical" cols="50" rows="2" name="Attr">
```

The page A opens page B in a popup (by `window.open('PageB')`).

In the page B, the button "Save" executes this line of code:

```
window.parent.opener.document.all.Attr.value='Value 1, Value 2,';
```

This one causes an error in Google Chrome (error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined") but works perfectly with Internet Explorer and Mozilla Firefox. I have read that `document.all` is old and should be replaced by `document.getElementById` which I did but with no success (error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null").

If I replace `document.all` by `document.forms[0]`, it works in all browsers including Google Chrome. But that doesn't seem to be a good solution as the page B could be called by other pages than Page A and that could have more than one form.

Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Opec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you just assign it an id an access it through that?

```
<textarea id="text" readonly wrap="Physical" cols="50" rows="2" name="Attr">
```

and in your javascript

```
document.getElementById("text").value="Value 1, value 2"
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/7NZtu/)  is a JSFiddle demonstrating it